# Decorator Pattern: WIll not run

Tags: c#, oop, design-patterns, visual-studio-2013, decorator

I am trying to implement the Decorator pattern, but I keep getting an error when I try to compile my program. I cannot figure out why. I know it has something to with something not being an interface, but I have tried a bunch of changes and nothing is working. I appreciate any assistance!

```
          using System;
          using System.Collections.Generic;
          using System.Linq;
          using System.Text;
          using System.Threading.Tasks;

          namespace OODAssignment3_ZackDavidson
          {
          class Program
          {
           static void Main(string[] args)
           {
            //Creates a new Calvin Klein Shirt fordecoration
            CalvinKlein ckShirt = new CalvinKlein();
            Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(ckShirt.GetBrand()));

            //Puts a solid color on the Calvin Klein Shirt
            solidColorDecorator ckSCD = new solidColorDecorator(ckShirt);

            //Puts stripes on the Calvin Klein Shirt
            stripedShirtDecorator ckSSD = new stripedShirtDecorator(ckShirt);

            //Puts a pocket on the Clavin Klein Shirt
            pocketShirtDecorator ckPSD = new pocketShirtDecorator(ckShirt);

            //Creates a new Tommy Hilfiger Shirt
            TommyHilfiger thShirt = new TommyHilfiger();

            //Puts stripes on the Tommy Hilfiger Shirt
            stripedShirtDecorator thSSD = new stripedShirtDecorator(thShirt);

            //Puts a pocket on the Tommy Hilfiger Shirt
            pocketShirtDecorator thPSD = new pocketShirtDecorator(thShirt); 
        }//EndOfMain
    }//EndOfClassProgram

    public abstract class ShirtsComponent
    {
        public abstract string GetBrand();
        public abstract double GetPrice();
    }

    class CalvinKlein : ShirtsComponent
    {
        private string ck_Brand = "Calvin Klein";
        private double ck_Price = 75.0;

        public override string GetBrand()
        {
            return ck_Brand;
        }

        public override double GetPrice()
        {
            return ck_Price;
        }
    }

    class TommyHilfiger : ShirtsComponent
    {
        private string th_Brand = "Tommy Hilfiger";
        private double th_price = 85.0;

        public override string GetBrand()
        {
            return th_Brand;
        }

        public override double GetPrice()
        {
            return th_price;
        }
    }

    public abstract class Decorator : ShirtsComponent
    {
        ShirtsComponent fashion_Base = null;

        protected string _brand = "Undefined Decorator";
        protected double _price = 0.0;

        protected Decorator(ShirtsComponent fashionBase)
        {
            fashion_Base = fashionBase;
        }

        #region ShirtsComponent Members

        string ShirtsComponent.GetBrand()
        {
            return string.Format("{0}, {1}", fashion_Base.GetBrand(), _brand);
        }

        double ShirtsComponent.GetPrice()
        {
            return _price + fashion_Base.GetPrice();
        }
        #endregion
    }

    class solidColorDecorator : Decorator
    {
        public solidColorDecorator(ShirtsComponent fashionBase)
            : base(fashionBase)
        {
            this._brand = "Solid Color Shirt";
            this._price = 25.0;
        }
    }

    class stripedShirtDecorator : Decorator
    {
        public stripedShirtDecorator(ShirtsComponent fashionBase)
            : base(fashionBase)
        {
            this._brand = "Striped Shirt";
            this._price = 50.0;
        }
    }

    class pocketShirtDecorator : Decorator
    {
        public pocketShirtDecorator(ShirtsComponent fashionBase)
            : base(fashionBase)
        {
            this._brand = "Dotted Shirt";
            this._price = 90.0;
        }
    }

}//EndOfNamespace
```

Comment: Always tag your questions with the appropriate language tags. (e.g. `c-sharp`)

Comment: Thank you. Sorry about that. The error says: Error 1 'IShirtsComponent' in explicit interface declaration is not an interface'

Answer (score 1):

This code is the problem:

```
    #region ShirtsComponent Members

    string ShirtsComponent.GetBrand()
    {
        return string.Format("{0}, {1}", fashion_Base.GetBrand(), _brand);
    }

    double ShirtsComponent.GetPrice()
    {
        return _price + fashion_Base.GetPrice();
    }
    #endregion
```

You don't need to specify the base class in the method declarations. This is the correct code:

```
    #region ShirtsComponent Members

    public override string GetBrand()
    {
        return string.Format("{0}, {1}", fashion_Base.GetBrand(), _brand);
    }

    public override double GetPrice()
    {
        return _price + fashion_Base.GetPrice();
    }
    #endregion
```

Comment: I changed the code in the #region area but I am still getting an error. Still says the ShirtsComponent is not an interface

Comment: line 110..exactly where I removed the base class

Comment: I forgot to include `override`. It is fixed now, should work fine.

Comment: Thank you so much, if I were going to ad a print function to this, would I put it in the base class?

Comment: Not in the abstract class. Possibly in the `Decorator` class. The reason why I say that is because a decorator pattern is almost always employed when you don't have the ability to make changes to the class being decorated. When you are able to make changes to the decorated class, then you can use inheritance instead of a decorator pattern. This code is a contrived example (I assume it is a learning exercise of some sort). You can mention to your teacher that it is a poor choice for learning the decorator pattern ;)